# hibernate "IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter"

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Here's my class hierarchy (lombok generated constructors/getters/setters ommitted for brevity):

```
public class A
{
    ... other variables ...

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<B> bSet = new HashSet<B>();
}

public class B
{
    ... other variables ...

    @CollectionOfElements
    @IndexColumn(name="index")
    private List<C> cList = new ArrayList<C>();
}

public class C
{
    ... other variables ...

    @Embedded
    private D[] dArray;
}

@Embeddable
public class D
{
    ... other variables ...

    private float f1;

    private float f2;
}
```

The problem is that when I save a new A instance that has stuff in the bSet, I get an IllegalArgumentException. Here's the relevant parts of the stack trace:

```
 org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of path.to.D.f1
    at path.to.dao.commitTransaction(PersistableDAO.java:32)
    at path.to.daoCaller(daoCaller.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    ... omitted for brevity ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of path.to.D.f1
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValues(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValues(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValues(ComponentType.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.deepCopy(ComponentType.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.getSnapshot(PersistentList.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CollectionEntry.<init>(CollectionEntry.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.addCollection(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:807)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.addNewCollection(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.WrapVisitor.processArrayOrNewCollection(WrapVisitor.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.WrapVisitor.processCollection(WrapVisitor.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.WrapVisitor.processValue(WrapVisitor.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.visitCollectionsBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:394)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:527)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:527)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1028)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at path.to.dao.commitTransaction(PersistableDAO.java:28)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
    ... 113 more
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't persist an array of Embeddable. In other words, the following is not supported:

```
public class C {
    ... other variables ...

    @Embedded
    private D[] dArray;
}
```

From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 2.1.5 Embeddable Classes
>
> An entity may use other fine-grained
>   classes to represent entity state.
>   Instances of these classes, unlike
>   entity instances themselves, do not
>   have persistent identity. Instead,
>   they exist only as embedded objects of
>   the entity to which they belong. Such
>   embedded objects belong strictly to
>   their owning entity, and are not
>   sharable across persistent entities.
>   Attempting to share an embedded object
>   across entities has undefined
>   semantics. **Because these objects
>   have no persistent identity, they are
>   typically mapped together with the
>   entity instance to which they
>   belong**.
>
> Embeddable classes must adhere to the
>   requirements specified in Section 2.1
>   for entities with the exception that
>   embeddable classes are not annotated
>   as `Entity`. Embeddable classes must
>   be annotated as `Embeddable` or
>   denoted in the XML descriptor as such.
>   The access type for an embedded object
>   is determined by the access type of
>   the entity in which it is embedded.
>   Support for only one level of
>   embedding is required by this
>   specification.
>
> Additional requirements on embeddable
>   classes are described in section
>   9.1.34.

JPA 2.0 added support for collections of embedded objects:

> #### 2.6 Collections of Embeddable Classes and Basic Types
>
> A persistent field or property of an
>   entity or embeddable class may
>   correspond to a collection of a basic
>   type or embeddable class (“element
>   collection”). Such a collection, when
>   specified as such by the
>   `ElementCollection` annotation, is
>   mapped by means of a collection table,
>   as defined in Section 11.1.8. If the
>   `ElementCollection` annotation (or XML
>   equivalent) is not specified for the
>   collection-valued field or property,
>   the rules of Section 2.8 apply.
>
> An embeddable class (including an
>   embeddable class within another
>   embeddable class) that is contained
>   within an element collection must not
>   contain an element collection, nor may
>   it contain a relationship to an entity
>   other than a many-to-one or one-to-one
>   relationship. The embeddable class
>   must be on the owning side of such a
>   relationship and the relationship must
>   be mapped by a foreign key mapping.
>   (See Section 2.9.)

But I still don't think you can map an array of Embeddable.

Comment: That was the problem. I managed to get around it by separating the array into individual instances (I suppose changing the array to a list would have worked too).